# Find the kernel of a 4x4 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
    5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
    9 & 10 & 11 & 12\\
    13 & 14 & 15 & 16\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

I am asked to find the kernel of the matrix $M$. After doing some row operation I get to 
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
    0 & -4 & -8 & -12\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

and for $x$ I find $x = \alpha + 2\beta$, whereas $y = -2\alpha -3\beta$
Therefore, 
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \alpha + 2\beta\\
    -2\alpha - 3\beta\\
    \alpha\\
    \beta\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

When we take outside alpha and beta:
we get two vectors:
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1\\
    -2\\
    1\\
    0\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2\\
    -3\\
    0\\
    1\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
which are linearly independent and form a basis of this $ker(M)$
Could you please confirm with me whether you get the same result? Thank you.

Comment: You can make your answer a little more symmetric (and maybe intuitive, given what the rows of the original matrix are) by replacing the second basis element with $(0,1,-2,1)^{\top}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is correct, in case of doubt you can check it directly by simple multiplication for RREF matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
    0 & -4 & -8 & -12\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    -2\\
    1\\
    0\\
    \end{bmatrix}=0$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
    0 & -4 & -8 & -12\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    2\\
    -3\\
    0\\
    1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
=0
$$

or/and also for the original matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
    5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
    9 & 10 & 11 & 12\\
    13 & 14 & 15 & 16\\
    \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    -2\\
    1\\
    0\\
    \end{bmatrix}=0$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
    5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
    9 & 10 & 11 & 12\\
    13 & 14 & 15 & 16\\
    \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    2\\
    -3\\
    0\\
    1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
=0
$$

Note that also after this check, for the correctness of the result it is crucial that RREF is calculated properly. In case of doubt on it we can evaluate $rank(M)$ with others methods or follow the nice [suggestion give by Atmos](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2661577/505767) to be sure that $dim(Ker M)=2$ and thus that what we have found is a basis for $Ker(M)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it looks good great. However, you should precise why the dimension of Kernel is $2$. For example by extracting the $2 \times 2$ determinant
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
 3&4 \\ 
 7&8 
\end{vmatrix}=24-28 \ne 0
$$
So the dimesion of the image is at least $2$. Then you found two vectors in it, so the dimension of the image cannot exceed two so it values $2$. as well as the dimension of the Kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Your computations are correct and so is your answer. But you should really improve your [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) skills.

Comment: I apologize. I am using this platform for the first time. Best.